# how to modify a cell value based on another cell value

Tags: excel, vba

```
A       B      C 
aa1     b1     ac1
aa2     b2     bd2
aa3     b3     ae3
aa4     b1     bc4
aa5     b2     ad5
aa6     b3     be6
```

now in the above sheet, i need to change the value like this..

```
A       B      C 
xy1     b1     ac1
aa2     b2     bd2
aa3     b3     ae3
aa4     b1     bc4
aa5     b2     ad5
pq6     b3     be6
```

as shown in the above part, based on the cells in the column "C" i need to change values in the column A for each cells of it..

Kindly help me...

Comment: I believe the first version of your question was correct, and now you made a mistake when you edited it. Now the columns A and C are messed up. As I understand you want column C to have values c1, c2, c3... and columns A values ac1, ac2, ac3... right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a formula in first cell of A and then simply propagate it across all the column.

1. In column A, select the cell with value "aa1"
2. Press F2 to edit that cell
3. Type `=CONCATENATE("a",$C1)` and press Enter
4. Press Ctrl+C to copy the cell you just edited
5. With the mouse (or with keys shift+down) select the next two cells in column A (aa2 and aa3)
6. Press Ctrl+V

In VBA, you need something like this:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A3").Cells
        cell.Value = "a" + ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.row, 3)
    Next
End Sub
```

You need to specify the range you want to change, in this case from A1 to A3 and then simply change the value for each cell as the concatenation of "a" with the cell value on same row but column 3 (C)

Comment: thanx a lot Jose for you reply..
i've modified the post to make my requirement clear..

actually i've more than 800entries in my excel, am badly need a macro instead of going over all those entries and modifying it..

Comment: thanx a lot Jose!!
with the one you've provided above was base for my solution..!!